# How to change the author information for nodes?

Tags: users, theming

Author information is disabled for all nodes (enter site). I was trying to enable it couldn't find the setting. I am currently using Drupal 7 and my theme is Omega.

I have given permissions to

> Execute Change the author of content

but still author information text box is disabled.

Please let me know how to change info.

---

Yes, I enabled the display of author and date information.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the content type is allowing the display of author and date information?